# classList.toggle Only Partially Works

Tags: javascript, function, onclick, font-awesome

I'm having a very confusing problem using classList.toggle and Font Awesome icons.  I want my hamburger menu to change to an X when clicked and I'm attempting to use a JavaScript function to accomplish this.  I just can't get it to work right.  The weird thing is, when I set the X as the default icon, and then change the icon class to the hamburger menu upon click, it works perfectly fine.  Here is my working code, changing the X to a hamburger:

```js
function myFunction(x) {
  x.classList.toggle("fa-bars");
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<div class="test">
  <i onclick="myFunction(this)" class="fa fa-times"></i>
</div>
```

That works fine.  But when I try to reverse the order, changing a hamburger to an X, it doesn't work.  Here's that code:

```js
function myFunction(x) {
  x.classList.toggle("fa-times");
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<div class="test">
  <i onclick="myFunction(this)" class="fa fa-bars"></i>
</div>
```

I've got to be missing something.  What is it?!

Comment: Toggling `fa-times` doesn't remove `fa-bars`, so you get `class="fa fa-bars fa-times"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do `toggle("fa-times")`, it doesn't remove the `fa-bars` class, it just adds or removes the `fa-times` class. And when the icon has `class="fa fa-bars fa-times"`, the `fa-bars` class has priority, so you see the hamburger.

You need to goggle both classes to make it work reliably. This will work no matter which class you set initially.

```js
function myFunction(x) {
  x.classList.toggle("fa-times");
  x.classList.toggle("fa-bars");
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<div class="test">
  <i onclick="myFunction(this)" class="fa fa-bars"></i>
</div>
```

Comment: works perfectly.  thank you for both the solution and explanation...appreciate the help!!!

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the old bars two , you can toggle the two classes and that's will work perfect at any order

```html
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head> 
<body>
<div class="test">
     <i onclick="myFunction(this)" class="fa fa-bars"></i>    
</div>

        <script>
        function myFunction(x) {
                x.classList.toggle("fa-times");
                x.classList.toggle("fa-bars");
                console.log(x.classList)
            }
        </script>
</body>
```